# How can I change the color of a button when I clicked the right answer? It is tested in PHP. (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, codeigniter

I have a number of rows with different buttons. When I click a button, it checks if it's the right answer in that row. This I have already working. What I can't figure out is how to give that right button (or wrong for that matter) a different color, so it shows that the user was correct (or wrong).
Any ideas?

This is in my controller:

```
//function for press exercises: exercises where you make decissions between buttons
public function press($ped_mat_id)
{
    if($this->input->post('answer'))
    {
        $answer = $this->input->post('answer');
        $evaluation = $this->Exercise->check_exercise_row($answer);

        if($evaluation)
        {
            //Code when the answer is correct
            echo 'correct';
            echo '<style type="text/css">
                button {
                    background-color: #11eb00 !important;
                }
                </style>';
        }
        else
        {
            //Code when the answer is wrong
            echo 'fout';
            echo '<style type="text/css">
                button {
                    background-color: #eb0000 !important;
                }
                </style>';
        }
    }   

    $this->_load_views('Oefen', 'exercises/press.php', $ped_mat_id);
}
```

This is in my model:

```
public function check_exercise_row($answer)
{
    $arr_answer = explode(',', $answer);
    $given_answer = $arr_answer[0];
    $exercise_id = $arr_answer[1];

    $result = $this->_get_solution($exercise_id);

    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
        $instruction = $row->exercise_instruction;
        $solution = $row->exercise_solution;    
    }

    $arr_instruction = explode(',',$instruction);

    $is_correct = false;

    if($given_answer == $arr_instruction[$solution])
    {
        $is_correct = true;
        $this->_insert_answer($given_answer, $exercise_id,$is_correct);
        return $is_correct;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->_insert_answer($given_answer, $exercise_id,$is_correct);
        return $is_correct;
    }
}
```

This is in my view:

```
<?php 
                    $dump = '<ul>';

                    foreach ($result as $row)
                    {
                        $label = $row->exercise_id;             

                        $arr_instructions = explode(',', $row->exercise_instruction);

                        $dump .= '<li><label>' . $label . '</label>';

                        foreach ($arr_instructions as $instruction)
                        {
                                                            if (in_array($label, $log) )
                            {
                                $dump .= '<button type="submit" disabled="disabled" name="answer" value="' . $instruction . ',' . $label .'">' . $instruction . '</button>';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $dump .= '<button type="submit" name="answer" value="' . $instruction . ',' . $label .'">' . $instruction . '</button>';    
                            }

                        }

                        $dump .= '</li>';
                    }
                    $dump .= '</ul>';
                    echo $dump;
                ?>
```

**EDIT:**
I've been looking into jQuery event.target stuff. And it looks I should be able to work with that, but I have no idea how to start. Anyone who does?

Comment: Why don't you use classes? Also using important is bad practice. Don't do it.

Comment: Yes, that was just for testing purposes. My bad. :)
Could you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to add a class to the specific button (ie: 'correct' or 'incorrect') and then add the relevant CSS to your stylesheet:

```
.correct{
    colour: #11eb00;
}
.incorrect{
    colour: #eb0000;
}
```

Comment: And how would I test to see which button has been clicked? That's where I'm a little stuck.

Comment: Ah I see.  Sorry, I'm not too hot on the PHP side of things, it's tagged as a CSS question.  Could you give each button a unique ID and pass that through?

Comment: How would I do that? :) The passing through I mean.